# Matching a value inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple app for retrieving stock information using the `stock_quote` gem. It's my first attempt at playing with an external dataset.

I'm currently able to find information on stocks by entering the ticker manually inside the controller:

```
    @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote('aapl')
```

How do I match what's inside of ('') e.g ('aapl') with a value, similar to what I normally do inside my views: #{@model.attribute}

I've tried to do,

```
 @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote('find_stock')
```

and then put `find_stock` method in a private method like this,

```
private

def find_stock
  params.find(params[:ticker])
end
```

But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might because you forget to permit the parameter,

```
  params.permit(:ticker)
```

Inspect the request in the console and see if you have the right parameter you want.

```
def find_stock
  ticket = params.permit(:ticker)
  StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticket)
end
```

For your information,

To get the parameter value, you need to pass the id. `{ticket: 'aapl}`, the id is `params[:ticket]` or `{stock: {ticket: 'aapl}}` you need to use `params[:stock][:ticket]`

Comment: No, everything passes correctly. No problems there.

Comment: Could it be because I need to pass the ID of the search query as well? Everything is under the show action, so naturally I'm already passing the ID... But it seems to me it doesn't know WHICH :ticker to look for. And that is because it's been throwing the same no method error with no regards to the corresponding action. I've also tried to loop everything inside an array, with the exact same error.

Comment: Yes, to get the parameter value, you need to pass the id. `{ticket: 'aapl}`, the id is `params[:ticket]` or `{stock: {ticket: 'aapl}}` you need to use `params[:stock][:ticket]`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just call the method?

```
  @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(find_stock)
```